# How to improve this Promise chaining and obtain same behaviour

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I need to make sure that the `prepare` function gets all the values before continuing its execution, that its why I am chaining the promises.

This code works but I need to do that for a lot of different values and the code is going to be a mess because the chaining actually has nesting (calling `getValue` inside the then with a `then` that has a `getValue` and so on)

So how can I achieve the same result with better practices or a cleaner approach

```
import { BackendService } from "../../core/backend.service";

export class Configuration {
  assetsBucketAccessKeyId: string ;
  assetsBucketSecretAccessKey: string ;
}

export namespace ConfigurationService {
  const configurations: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  const configurationURL = "configuration";
  export const values = new Configuration() ;

  export function prepare(backendService: BackendService) {
    ConfigurationService
      .getValue("assetsBucketAccessKeyId", backendService)
      .then(v1 => {values.assetsBucketAccessKeyId = v1; } )
      .then(() => { ConfigurationService
        .getValue("assetsBucketSecretAccessKey", backendService)
        .then(v2 => {values.assetsBucketSecretAccessKey = v2; } ); }) ;
  }

 export function getValue(
    keyName: string,
    backendService: BackendService
  ): Promise<string> {
    let resp: string;

    resp = null;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // find or query te value
      if (!configurations[keyName]) {
        const requestURL = `${configurationURL}/${keyName}`;

        backendService.get<string>(requestURL).subscribe(
          value => {
            configurations[keyName] = value;
            resolve(value);
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
            reject(null);
          }
        );
      } else {
        resolve(configurations[keyName]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javaScripts async/await sytax for handling promises e.g.

```
export async function prepare(backendService: BackendService) {
    values.assetsBucketAccessKeyId = await ConfigurationService.getValue("assetsBucketAccessKeyId", backendService);
    values.assetsBucketSecretAccessKey = await ConfigurationService.getValue("assetsBucketSecretAccessKey", backendService);
}
```

This approach leads to easier to read code when using promises.

You then have a number of ways to call this function.

1) Call it using Promise code e.g.

```
prepare(backendService).then(() => { // assetsBucketAccessKeyId/assetsBucketSecretAccessKey will now be available})
```

2) Call it from another async method e.g.

```
async function wrapper() {
 await prepare(backendService)
 // assetsBucketAccessKeyId/assetsBucketSecretAccessKey now available to access...
}
```

3) Call it from an anonymous function e.g.

```
(async () => {
  await prepare(backendService)
  // assetsBucketAccessKeyId/assetsBucketSecretAccessKey now available to access...
})();
```

Comment: this makes the prepare function 'async' so how do I wait on that ? sorry for newbie question

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez You can either make the function which calls your prepare function an async method or you can wrap it in an anonymous async action e.g. (async () => {
  let response = await prepare(backendService);})(); [This](https://javascript.info/async-await) is a good article on async/await.

Comment: I've seen your other comment. I'll put detail on how to use this function in the answer.

Comment: There is something weird going on here, when I check the values inside the prepare they are ok, but when I access them outside the prepare function using Configution.values all values seem to be undefined

Comment: Your result is undefined probably because your async function hasn't actually run or completed. See my updated answer on how to call it and ensure the results are available.

Comment: thanks for all the effort, my issue was that I was calling prepare in the wrong place, If I could upvote this more times I would ;-)

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since target functions are already promisified, you can use async await ES6 syntax.

Example:

```
export async function prepare(backendService: BackendService) {
    values.assetsBucketAccessKeyId = await ConfigurationService.getValue(
          'assetsBucketAccessKeyId',
          backendService
        );
    values.assetsBucketSecretAccessKey = await ConfigurationService.getValue(
          'assetsBucketSecretAccessKey',
          backendService
       );
}
```

Don't forget to add `async` in front of function name and `await` in front of function call.

`Note:` If any of your function is not returning a promise then this will not work.

Comment: but then the ´prepare´ function will execute async and i need it to execute completly before the next line is called

Comment: Async await  will work same as `.then()` thing.
It will execute line by line only... Await will wait till data is received.
Just async await will make code looks better, else functionality will be same and you need not to assign v1,v2 extra variables.

Comment: And writing async in front of prepare function will make it promise as well, so anywhere you use prepare function, you can await for it as well.

Comment: From where you are calling prepare?
Write await in front of prepare function call as well if you wish to wait for prepare function execution as well.

Comment: Does your current implementation works fine?
If yes then just replace the body of prepare function with code provided by me. It will work same.

Comment: @ATULSHARMA This is exactly the same as my answer which I left 25 minutes earlier.

Comment: HI @BenSmith , Oh sorry, I haven't read it. and re-write whole code in my editor and solved his query. Because Async await has this solution only, so might be our answers get same. But explained him more, in answer as well as in comments. Hope you don't mind it.

Comment: I will try @BenSmith comment to see if it works, it will be best to have an answer with the details explained in the answer and not in comments

Comment: Thanks for you answer but since the same answer came in first and is more detailed I have accepted that one

Answer (score 0):

Provided you know all of the keys upfront, you could just run through the promises in series. The series logic is pretty gnarly but it's basically a utility method to employ anywhere for this purpose.

The changes below are all the changes, everything else in your code is unchanged.

You may need to refactor your code a little to handle passing context to the serialized resolved callbacks but that's easy.

I used es7 but you can convert if you want.

Let me know if you need any more explanation.

```js
export async function serializedRun<T>(promiseFunctions: (() => Promise<T>)[], callback: (T) => void) {
  // se below for reasoning of the null \/ here
    return await [...promiseFunctions, null ].reduce(async (prevPromise, nextPromise, index) => {
        const result = await prevPromise;

    // Skip initalValue promise
    if (index === 0) {
      // Do something cool with each result
      callback(result)
    }else if (nextPromise !== null) { // Skip final value
      // you need a another cycle beyond the last promise to await the last returned promise
            return nextPromise();
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(result); // Final resolved value
        }
    }, Promise.resolve()); // ininitalValue promise to start the cycle
}

export namespace ConfigurationService {
  const configurations: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  const configurationURL = "configuration";
  const keyNames = [
    'assetsBucketAccessKeyId',
    'assetsBucketSecretAccessKey',
  ]

  export const values = new Configuration() ;

  export async function prepare(backendService: BackendService) {
    await serializedRun(
      // This looks crazy below but you don't want to evoke the promise yet
      // So you need to return a function that the serializedRun method can invoke
      keyNames.map((key) => () => ConfigurationService.getValue(key, backendService)),
      (value) => {
        // You need to figure out a way pass the required params to this funciton
        // for it to know what to do...
        if (/* something */) {
          values.assetsBucketAccessKeyId = value;
        } else {
          values.assetsBucketSecretAccessKey = value;
        }
      })
  }
```

> NOTE: You would also need to handle any errors in the serializedRun method with `try`/`catch` blocks

Comment: thanks for your answer, this sounds extremly ofuscated and I am actually trying to make my code more readable